# Remove "OneDrive" from path in onedrive folder

Tags: windows, backup

I'm trying to setup a simple backup solution for a small office of a few people. We have a windows server with two disks in Raid 1 (mirrored) for saving files that can be reached both in office and from outside through a VPN. This folder is located at `V:\Vault`.

As an extra precation in case of robbery or fire we are thinking of saving the contents of this folder to OneDrive (as we are using it for other things already anyways).

Here comes the problem. Onedrive apparently requires you to put all your files in a folder path which ends in OneDrive, ie `"V:\Vault\OneDrive"`. Even if you select a different location it automatically adds the "OneDrive" part to the end.

My question: Is there a way to get around this so that the onedrive folder is simply V:\Vault through some setting or other trikkery. I'm fine with regedit changes if it can be accomplished that way.

I would prefer not to change the folder structure/path because OneDrive has stupid settings/requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Onedrive is a consumer product and isn't meant as a commercial backup target. Rather than trying to shoehorn it into your backup architecture, why not look at something much simpler and more suited for the task, such as [Azure Backup](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/backup/)